# Regarding how browser interprets HTML/CSS/Javascript

Tags: javascript, html, css

I am pretty green to web development.

In one of my courses I have been told the following things will happen when browser reads a web page.

At a very high level I assume this is the basic flow.

1.Browser pulls the HTML page.

2.Browser understands the document structure using the HTML tags.

3.After step 2, browser understands the CSS selectors/properties.

4.Browser builds the DOM model now.

5.After this, the javascript interpreter within the browser interprets the .js script

**Questions**

1.Is the above flow correct ?

2.I am aware that the HTML tags can be manipulated by javascript.

Are the CSS selectors are also part of DOM and can be manipulated by javascript ?

Comment: JavaScript is not necessarily run only after the DOM is ready...

Comment: This is not really correct in several ways. The process by which a page is loaded in a modern browser is pretty complicated, with lots of possibilities for different behaviors based on tag attributes. A complete answer would be a significant amount of text.

Comment: Have a look at this http://www.html5rocks.com/en/tutorials/internals/howbrowserswork/

Comment: As Pointy says, it's extremely complex and while procedural in general, there are lots of optimisations and interrupts. Consider how HTML error correction and scripts might affect the DOM along the way.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Not exactly correct. It's a complicated process.

JavaScript isn't run just after the entire page is loaded, which is why you'll see a lot of junior programmers make the mistake of trying to manipulate HTML, without checking if the page has loaded.

When the browser reaches an element such as `<script>` or `<link>` it will attempt to pull the resource, and if successful, will then execute that resource. Meaning the JavaScript code, for instance, will run before the DOM has loaded, if the `<script>` tag is in the head (where it usually is). CSS works in a similar way, however it doesn't really matter when CSS is applied, in most cases, since it can't crash. You can create styles and even change the inline styles of elements, using JavaScript, but a general rule of thumb is to keep styles that CAN be in .css files there.

Comment: "*`<script>` tag is in the head (where it usually is)*" in *most* cases it is better to put the `script` tag/s at the end of the page right *before* `</body>`, this is better to improve page load and I think this way you don't need to check for DOM ready.. Although this is *not always* the case, IMO some scripts perform might be better to be included in the head like modernizr to check for browserX supports a certain feature or not, Updovted